# Surface shader ignores lighting in vertexLit path

Tags: unity, shaders, lighting

I want to use a surface shader in VertexLit(not Forward) rendering path. I caused a problem that the compiled shader completely ingnores lighting from the light sources on the scene.
Here's the code:

```
Shader "Custom" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "LightMode" = "Vertex" }
        LOD 200

        Lighting On

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Lambert
        #pragma target 3.0


        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    } 
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I really need this shader to work. Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Try delete  Tags { "LightMode" = "Vertex" }

Comment: You might want to add a bit more information. Like *why* this should work, and what you think the problem it's solving is.

Comment: Not working. Maybe I need to do something more?